# MarkerOptions tap on info box

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have application with google map v2 containing couple of MarkerOptions inside it. Is there a way to catch tap on info box that is opened after pin is tapped?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
               // do something
            }
        });
```

Probably duplicate question.

Comment: Yep you are right, probably this is duplicate question. I was looking for possibility to attach handler directly on marker, and because of that i failed to find the correct answer. But this solution seems to do the magic, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

```
  GoogleMap mMap;   
 Marker  myMarker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lng)
            .title("Head Quarter Office")
            .snippet("Delhi")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    if(arg0.getTitle().equals("Marker")) // if marker source is clicked
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arg0.getTitle(),1000).show();// display toast
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Comment: Tnx for suggested solution, but as far i can see, this catches tap on marker, and not on info window.